# Can GraphRNN be used with very large graphs?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, papers, geometric-deep-learning

In the [GraphRNN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08773.pdf), the authors only implement the algorithm up to a graph size of 2k nodes. Would this still work on much larger graphs (on the order of $10^7$)? Or would the computation just become too substantial?